# What is the yii equivalent of exception_notification?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yii

What is the yii equivalent of exception_notification?

Be able to:

- Send Emails of errors received in production

Answer (score 1):

You can set up an [CEmailLogRoute](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CEmailLogRoute) which sends an email to an address whenever the route was trigered. See [here for more info](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.logging) on logging.